# Console showing "Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set" CSP error even when 'img-src' is set with Electron

Tags: image, electron, content-security-policy

In an Electron renderer, I am trying to load an image via a custom protocol but in the renderer console I am getting the following error:

```
main_window:13 Refused to load the image 'dir://pumpjack.png' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data:". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

Even though I have set the img-src explicitly. My `index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * 'self' dir:">
    <title>Star Domain</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="dir://pumpjack.png">
    <div id="board"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I remove the `index.html` img-src from the meta tag so it only reads:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

I get two errors for Content Security Policy:

```
main_window:13 Refused to load the image 'dir://pumpjack.png' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data:". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

main_window:13 Refused to load the image 'dir://pumpjack.png' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I am using an Electron app with default configuration which I created using

```
yarn create electron-app "Star Domain" --template=webpack-typescript
```

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix my Content Security Policy? Note that JS and CSS are loading properly with this CSP setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused Electron Forge's webpack dev server adding Content Security Policy HTTP header to the index.html that it's serving. Note that this doesn't happen with a distributable Electron app because it doesn't use such dev server.

You can solve this by changing the Electron Forge config in your project in `forge.config.ts` by setting webpack plugin property `devContentSecurityPolicy`. You can set it to your actual CSP or if you set it to an empty string, there will be no headers added to the index.html file and the behavior will be the same as it is in distributable app by default.

```
  plugins: [
    new AutoUnpackNativesPlugin({}),
    new WebpackPlugin({
      mainConfig,
      devContentSecurityPolicy: '',
```

Answer (score 1):

The default-src in the policy you have shown and the error message are different. This means that there are multiple policies in place for your page. There are likely default policies added by your framework (or webserver, load balancer etc). Look at the response headers and try to identify how those policies are set to be able to modify or remove them.